# Burndown Trend - Graph not showing Remaining work

Tags: azure-devops, burndowncharts

We have started our new sprint and in burndown trend ( Azure Devops ) we can not see remaing work in the graph.

[image: 1]

At the same time in capacity tab, we can see efforts have been planned for the current iteration.

[image: 2]

Are we missing anything.

**UPDATE 1**

Burn down is based on sum of remaining work and every task has value associated with it.  In following image you can see remaining work is 106.  But still its not reflected in graph.

[image: Remaining work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that on the first day of the sprint there's nothing to burndown. If you hover your mouse over to the far left of the chart, it will highlight the work items that will burndown.

There's also a few different options for the chart. Click through the **View the full report** to see:

- Which backlog are you burning down -- Tasks or Stories? or individual work items?
- What are you burning down? Count of work items, Sum of completed work or remaining work?

Note, if you're burning down remaining work your tasks will need remaining work filled out to be useful.

Comment: please have a look at UPDATE 1 in original question.  We are burning down tasks and sum of remaining work.

Comment: You accepted the answer, what was the issue? did the tasks not have remaining hours filled out, or was it just because it was the first day of the sprint?